# How can we post message to google plus by oauth api?

Tags: php

I have went through google api documentation and so many reference links. but i have never seen related to google plus post message. In Google API Documentation They shows

Note: The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data. All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key.

Is there any other way to implement this?. Please, can any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data.

That means the API is *read-only*. You cannot post anything on Google+ through the API as of the time of this writing.

Answer (score 1):

According to me , there is not api documentaion for that message .

**Google+** API Provide:

- Search People
- List Comments
- ListByActivity People
- Search Activities
- Get People
- Get Comments
- Get Activities
- List Activities

Comment: If u got then choose best answer and close your question.